# Pride of the humble

Tags: protestantism, eastern-orthodox

Some Russian so called "saints" talked much about what they call "pride of the humble" (when one is proud by his own humility: "I am a great saint").

My question: Do similar ideas appear in western Protestantism? Is it a common trend?

Comment: Yes, hypocrites exist pretty much everywhere, regardless of religious background. How is this unique to Christianity, or Christian doctrinal teaching?

Comment: @DavidStratton: I do not ask about hypocrites, but about classification of a special kind of hypocrites in the religion

Comment: Humility is a funny thing. As soon as you think you have it, chances are you don't! A verse from Romans 12:  "For through the grace given to me I say to everyone among you not to think more highly of himself than he out to think; but to thing so as to have sound judgment, as God has allotted to each a measure of faith" (v.3). Most Western Protestants would likely agree with this verse.

Comment: Being proud, or rather outright arrogant, over your supposed humility?  That's called Calvinism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this idea is found in Western Protestantism. You can find a (fictitious) example described in C.S. Lewis' *The Screwtape Letters*, where the senior devil is advising the junior tempter that "every time your subject shows real humility, show him that fact, and do your best to make him proud of having achieved it".